# Javascript: Function only works correctly when used single instance in code

Tags: javascript, hl7, mirth

When I use the function below the only time it returns successfully is if I only use it against a single string. If I try to call the function multiple times in code against different unique strings, it returns an "unparsable date" error.

```
function oraDate(str) {
    if(str.length > 0){
        channelMap.put("StringCount", str.length);
        if(str.length == 8){
            channelMap.put("8 characters", "Date only");
            var date = str.substring(0, 8);
            var cDate = DateUtil.convertDate("yyyyMMdd", "yyyy-MM-dd", date);
            return cDate + 'T' + '00:00:00';

        } else if(str.length == 12){
            channelMap.put("12 characters", "Date/time only");
            var date = str.substring(0, 8);
            var time = str.substring(8, 12);
            var cDate = DateUtil.convertDate("yyyyMMddHHmm", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm", date);
            return cDate+':00';

        } else if(str.length >= 14){
            channelMap.put("14 characters", "Date/time w/seconds only");
            var date = str.substring(0, 8);
            var time = str.substring(8, 14);
            var date_time = date+time;
            var cDate = DateUtil.convertDate("yyyyMMddHHmmss", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", date_time);
            return cDate;
        }

    } else {
        return '0001-01-01T00:00:00';   
    }
}
```

Comment: as error says, one of the times you are calling the function string format does not correspond to a date format...

Comment: What is`channelMap`? What is `DateUtil.convertDate`?  Where is the error thrown?

Comment: In the `12` case, you never use `time` but only `date`. Maybe that's a problem for the parser?

Comment: channelMap is global. Try to define channelMap locally in the function, so it gets reset everytime the function is called.

Comment: You'll need to post the code you're calling the function from,  as well as let us know where it is (transformer,  javascript reader/writer etc).
Also, Mirth version.

Comment: I fixed this the other day and forgot to come back to post the solution. I had to add 'var date_time = date+time;' to the 12 count and change the date variable in the pattern to 'date_time'

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to come back here to post the fix. I missed the "date_time" variable for the 12 character check.

```
function oraDate(str) {
if(str.length > 0){
    channelMap.put("StringCount", str.length);
    if(str.length == 8){
        channelMap.put("8 characters", "Date only");
        var date = str.substring(0, 8);
        var cDate = DateUtil.convertDate("yyyyMMdd", "yyyy-MM-dd", date);
        return cDate + 'T' + '00:00:00';

    } else if(str.length == 12){
        channelMap.put("12 characters", "Date/time only");
        var date = str.substring(0, 8);
        var time = str.substring(8, 12);
        var date_time = date+time;
        var cDate = DateUtil.convertDate("yyyyMMddHHmm", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm", date_time);
        return cDate+':00';

    } else if(str.length >= 14){
        channelMap.put("14 characters", "Date/time w/seconds only");
        var date = str.substring(0, 8);
        var time = str.substring(8, 14);
        var date_time = date+time;
        var cDate = DateUtil.convertDate("yyyyMMddHHmmss", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss", date_time);
        return cDate;
    }

} else {
    return '0001-01-01T00:00:00';
}
```

}